# New project - should I learn new language or use a language I already know

Tags: new-project

Afternoon.

I have left the names of the languages out of the question, to keep it general and to stop flame wars.

I am about to start a new project, and I would usually use language A. I am good at language A but it's the only 'web' language I know.

Languages B and C also interest me but I haven't used them at all before therefore it's hard to justify starting a project with them.

Project based learning is a good way to learn, so I guess...

a) Stick with what you know, you'll get the job done faster
b) Try with new language, it might just be better than the other

I am leaning towards b, I think it's good to branch out.

Hmmm

Comment: I'm guessing A is PHP, B is Python, and C is Ruby.  But especially since you left the names out, this belongs on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: I like the question but it is pretty subjective. +1 for moving to Programmers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good to branch out, but it heavily depends on context. Is this a project for work, or recreation? If it's just a hobby program, then I certainly recommend trying out a new technology because, as you say, project-based learning is really helpful. However, if it's a work-related project and you're on a deadline, then clearly you should "stick with what you know", as you put it.

A factor that affects how viable the second language would be is how well-documented the features of that language that you'll be using are, as well as how much example code there is related to what you'll want to accomplish.